# Edit HTTP response headers for an application in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have a set of applications running in my IIS Server 7.0. I need to "Expire Web Content" of one of those applications through command line. Running appcmd.exe works, but it changes this configuration for all the applications in IIS. Is there a way to do this for a single application?

This is the command which I ran.

appcmd.exe set config /section:staticContent /clientCache.cacheControlMode:DisableCache

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command, just replace "SITENAME" with your site id.

appcmd.exe set config "SITENAME" /section:staticContent /clientCache.cacheControlMode:DisableCache

Comment: Right now I have only two Sites. "Default Web Site" is having a SiteId of 2 and this Site has a lot of applications running. If I put SiteId 2 in the command suggested in your comment, the changes will be done for all the applications. But I dont want to do the configuration change for all those applications. I just want the changesto be done for a single application. Is there any way?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response: The "SITENAME" parameter can include the requested application: For example: "Default Web Site/app1" will only affect "app1".